# Using Spy++ in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, spy++

I am writing a program in Windows 8.
Now I come across a problem when using SPY++.

Usually, we can get "Window Proc" from SPY++ in Windows 7.
But in Windows 8, I can only get "(Unavailable)(Unicode)".
The program I had tried is "Install Wizard".

Did anyone come across the familiar problem as well?
How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You may be using Spy++ 32-bit to spy on a 64-bit application.  Try using Spy++ 64-bit.